# HAProxy use urls in server config?

Tags: haproxy

Right now, my config looks like this:

```
server node1 10.20.x.y:80 check
server node2 10.20.x.y:80 check
server node3 10.20.x.y:80 check
```

What would be the best way to use URLS here instead of IPs?

Something like (But this does not seem to work):

```
server node1 url-1.google.com:80 check
server node2 url-2.google.com:80 check
server node3 url-3.google.com:80 check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use hostnames rather than IP-addresses that is called DNS resolution in HAproxy jargon.  You will need to specify a [*"resolvers"*](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#5.3.2) section where you configure DNS. For instance:

```
resolvers mydns
  nameserver dns1 10.0.0.1:53
  nameserver dns2 10.0.0.2:53
  resolve_retries       3
  timeout resolve       1s
  timeout retry         1s
  hold other           30s
  hold refused         30s
  hold nx              30s
  hold timeout         30s
  hold valid           10s
  hold obsolete        30s
```

Then you must precise one `resolvers` parameter on each server line where DNS
  resolution is required.

```
server s1 app1.example.com:80 resolvers mydns resolve-prefer ipv6
```

**Extra Credit** Rather than enumerating each node in your config you can also use a round-robin DNS record in your URL. That means you can also reduce the configuration changes needed when you add/remove nodes from your cluster to only changing the DNS record.

A DNS record would then look like:

```
app1.example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1 
app1.example.com. IN A 192.0.2.2 
app1.example.com. IN A 192.0.2.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it also possible to make it recheck the dns every X min?

Comment: How frequently DNS is rechecked is defined by the `hold` directives, `hold valid           10s` is the default

Comment: Is it possible to recheck the DNS on failures (e.g. 503 status from a health check) rather than at a specific time interval?

Comment: @user3738870 off-hand I don’t know but DNS is more about node discovery , while enabling / disabling discovered nodes based on their health happens somewhat separately with the `check` directive , I think (but as I said I don’t know exactly)

Comment: @HBruijn would you be so kind in helping to fix haproxy.cfg?